# Try to Assign a value from a textbox to a devexpress gridview

Tags: gridview, textbox, devexpress

I have a textbox and a button. On click of the button i would like to assign that value to the gridview.

However, I dont want to go through a stored procedure or any update to database table to do this..i just want the front end and then click a print button which sends the value to the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table and have columns defined in that table.

Bind the grid to that table.

Once you click the button, you can add the value to the existing table of values and bind the grid again.

let me know if you need more help regarding the same.

Thanks.